# How to prevent popup get focus when popup show

Tags: windows-8, popup, microsoft-metro, focus

If set popup's IsLightDismissEnabled = true ，when popup show ,popup will get focus , other control will lost focus.
My question :How can I keep the focus;when the popup show ?

Answer (score 1):

That's counter-intuitive, in my opinion.  `IsLightDismissEnabled` effectively means "show this popup, but once it loses focus hide it".  If you aren't giving your popup focus, or setting focus to another control programmatically, it will either show until you carry on interacting with your form, or not show at all (not sure which, I haven't checked it)